# Remove duplicate substrings from a string

Tags: ruby, string

```
str = "hi ram hi shyam hi jhon"
```

I want something like:

```
"ram hi shyam hi jhon"
"ram shyam hi jhon"
```

Answer (score 10):

I assume you want to remove duplicate occurrences of all words, not just `"hi"`. Here are two ways of doing that.

**1 Use [String#reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-reverse), [Array#reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse) and [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)**

```
str = "hi shyam ram hi         shyam hi jhon"

str.split.reverse.uniq.reverse.join(' ')
  #=> "ram shyam hi jhon"
```

The doc for `uniq` states: "`self` is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept."

**2 Use a regular expression**

```
r = /
    \b      # match a word break
    (\w+)   # match a word in capture group 1
    \s      # match a trailing space
    (?=     # begin a positive lookahead
      .*    # match any number of characters
      \s    # match a space
      \1    # match the contents of capture group 1
      \b    # match a word break
    )       # end the positive lookahead
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.gsub(r, '')
  #=> "ram         shyam hi jhon"
```

To remove the extra spaces change `\s` to `\s+` in the third line of the regex definition.

Comment: And this guy was joking about me taking off my medicine! Upvoted :)

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "hi ram hi shyam hi jhon"
```

To remove one occurrence:

```
str.sub('hi', '').strip.squeeze
#⇒ "ram hi shyam hi jhon"
```

To remove n occurrences:

```
n.times { str.replace(str.sub('hi', '').strip.squeeze) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`sub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub-21):

```
str = "hi ram hi shyam hi jhon"

str.sub!("hi ", "")
#=> "ram hi shyam hi jhon"

str.sub!("hi ", "")
#=> "ram shyam hi jhon"

str.sub!("hi ", "")
#=> "ram shyam jhon"
```

In-case you do not what to modify your original string, which is not how the example looks like, you might want to use `sub` instead and an extra variable